# Create new categories without changing yaml files

Tags: bolt-cms, bolt

Our client wants to have control over categories and I need to make it possible without changing yaml files. Any idea?

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and where you got stuck.

Comment: Hey. I just can't find solution since I know that categories are defined in yaml file and don't know any way to fill it dynamically. My case is website with cooking recipes and client wants to have control not only over single recipes, but also categories of them.

Answer (score 1):

Create a ContentType called Categories and let the users make relationships to it.

Answer (score 0):

Have the ContentType use Tags instead of Categories. With tags, the editor can add more, on the fly.

Otherwise, give them a 5-minute introduction on how yaml works. ;-)